# Google Cloud Dataflow error NoSuchMethodException: No such function

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, user-defined-functions, nashorn

I am using a dataflow function to transform pubsub messages in the form of json written as a string to submit into a bigquery table with the correct schemas in place.

I use the following UDF function which I have tested to work correctly in the google cloud shell.

```
function networkprocess(inJson) {
  data = JSON.parse(inJson);

  data ["Network_Details"] = JSON.parse(data["Network_Details"]);
  index = data["Network_Details"]["IpAddress"].indexOf(data["source_internal_ip"]);
  if (index == -1) {
      index = 0;
    }
  for (var key in data["Network_Details"]){
      data[key] = (data["Network_Details"][key][index]);
    }
  

  delete  data ["Network_Details"];
 return JSON.stringify(data);
}
```

However this dataflow job keeps outputting failed records to a failed record table with the following error:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: No such function networkprocess  at
> org.openjdk.nashorn.api.scripting.ScriptObjectMirror.callMember(ScriptObjectMirror.java:192)
> at .......
>
> ............ a lot of "at" pointers....

I have tried creating new UDFs from scracth as well as using the standard function google provides when clicking create UDF during the job set up (in GUI) which is just:

```
function process(inJson) {

 return JSON.stringify(data);
}
```

and it they all return the same error that it cannot find the function.

I am deploying this via GUI or terraform but its the same result.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like the function is not loaded properly, somehow.

You saved the JavaScript file in a GCS bucket, and pointed to it using the right path?

Does the [service account](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/concepts/security-and-permissions#df-service-account) that is being used in Dataflow has the right set of permissions to fetch that file?

Comment: yes and I beleiev so. How can I check with SA is being used by Dataflow to call the function?

The one I expect it to use has the following roles:
> * Storage Admin
> * Storage Object Admin
> * Storage Object Creator.

In any case I created a rule from scratch using the GUI and GC templates, use their own basic function and it still had the same problem.

I'm sure this was working when I first tested it about 2 or 3 weeks ago so I'm struggling to understand why it can't see the function suddenly

Answer (score 0):

Might sound like a silly suggestion, but maybe it is some error on Google's side and you should just contact [Google Support](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/support/getting-support) directly.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. Check if you file name ends with .js. In my case that was the problem.
I had this gs://bucket-name/file-name and I had the same error than you.
I changed to gs://bucket-name/file-name.js and the problem was solved.